# Adding objects to listview dynamically from other class in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

My project includes an "accept/deny incoming data" window that on "accept" should add the incoming data dynamically to a listview and the database that the listview gets the data from. My listadapter is an inner class.

My code in the main class relating to the populating of the listview:

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private List<Assignment> allDeliveries= new ArrayList<Assignment>();
     

    
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        populateDeliveryList();
        populateListView();
        registerClickCallBack();
        final MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

        accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout newdeliverylayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.newdeliverylayout);
                allDeliveries.add(incomingAssignment);
                db.addAssignment(incomingAssignment);
                MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        deny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout newdeliverylayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.newdeliverylayout);
                newdeliverylayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
            }
        });

    private void populateDeliveryList() {
        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
                List<Assignment> list = db.getAllAssignments();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++)
        {
            allDeliveries.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
                                            
    private void populateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<Assignment> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deliveriesListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }                                           


                                       
}
```

This is my inner class, the listadapter:

```html
    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Assignment> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_view, allDeliveries);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
            }

            Assignment nyDelivery = allDeliveries.get(position);


            TextView adressText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_adressView);
            adressText.setText(nyDelivery.getAdress());

            TextView zipText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_zipcodePlaceView);
            zipText.setText(nyDelivery.getZipcode());

            TextView companyText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_companyView);
            companyText.setText(nyDelivery.getSenderreceiver());

            TextView typeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_driveTypeView);
            typeText.setText(nyDelivery.getType() + nyDelivery.getID());

            return itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

The code in "accept" seems to do nothing except adding the incoming assignment to the database.

Comment: you seem to create the listAdapter twice once on the onCreate method in the populateListView call then when the user click on the accept button in your onClick method.  But I am still not clear on what exactly is the issue.

Comment: I tried just calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but the program does not run then, it cannot find symbol adapter. I figured I had to create a new instance of the class to sort of "rebuild" the itemview but I'm not sure thats how it works, im fairly new to android

Comment: it is not going to be found if it is defined locally in the populateListView method, you need define it in you ArrayAdapter<Assignment> adapter as a global variable in the your class.

Comment: let me know if this is not clear, i will post the changes I am recommending to your MainActivity class in answer

Comment: If you don't mind writing the changes, I would love to see them. I have more things to work on with this project and if I'm programming impractically I would love to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a simple change of declaring MyListAdapter in your MainActivity and instantiate it once in the populateListView,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private List<Assignment> allDeliveries= new ArrayList<Assignment>();
    MyListAdapter adapter;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        populateDeliveryList();
        populateListView();
        registerClickCallBack();
        final MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

        accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout newdeliverylayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.newdeliverylayout);
                allDeliveries.add(incomingAssignment);
                db.addAssignment(incomingAssignment);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        deny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout newdeliverylayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.newdeliverylayout);
                newdeliverylayout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
            }
        });

    private void populateDeliveryList() {
        MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        List<Assignment> list = db.getAllAssignments();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++)
        {
            allDeliveries.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deliveriesListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }                                           

}
```